# Google warns developer to include 64-bit version for Android app

Tags: android, cordova, 32bit-64bit, crosswalk, cordova-android

Google is [warning developers](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/01/get-your-apps-ready-for-64-bit.html) that starting Aug 1, 2019, all apps must be 64-bit.

I use [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) to build our web app into an Android app and upload the generated 32-bit APK file into google play store

The [Cordova crosswalk plugin](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview) allow me to build both 32-bit and 64-bit versions using the commands `cordova build android --release` and `cordova build android --release --xwalk64bit` respectively.

I used the same android version code for both the APKs when build

**Questions:**

1. Earlier I used to upload only the 32-bit version into the play store(Production Track). Right now, Since I have both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of APKs, should I upload both of the APKs into play store to support 32-bit and 64-bit mobiles?
2. What would be the process to upload both of 32-bit and 64-bit versions into production release? There is [Google doc](https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks) about multiple APKs but there is no mention about 32-bit and 64-bit versions.
3. Will play store take care of delivering 32-bit APK to 32-bit mobile and 64-bit APK to 64-bit mobile?

***Note:*** I can't generate `.aab` using [Android App Bundle package format](https://developer.android.com/platform/technology/app-bundle) since [cordova-android](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/) is not started supporting yet and there is a [Github issue](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/issues/729) created for that

Answer (score 1):

I was facing issue in play store when uploading both 32-bit and 64-bit versions. It seems there an issue with crosswalk plugin while generating version code during the build. The issue is explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/43570109/2474301

I had to make plugin code change as the answer explained in the StackOverflow link

After I made both 32-bit and 64-bit builds with proper version code, I'm able to upload both 32-bit and 64-bit APKs into google play store. Both the APKs are delivered to the appropriate mobile.